# Selenium ChromeDriver - Remember "Always Allow" setting for getUserMedia webcam access

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, getusermedia

I've got a page running on a local webserver, on an https page, that uses the getUserMedia API to do some photobooth-style webcam stuff.

In ChromeDriver, the browser won't remember the "Always allow" setting for allowing webcam access. I'm given the option, and it remembers that preference while the browser's running, but once I quit/re-open, the prompt returns.

I'm running Chromedriver 26.0.1383.0.

Does anybody know how to make that preference stick around permanently?

Comment: What language are you running Selenium with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. I solved it by doing the following in C#

```
var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
var options = new ChromeOptions();

options.AddArgument("use-fake-device-for-media-stream");
options.AddArgument("use-fake-ui-for-media-stream");

var ChromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, options);
```

It's very similar to [siddhadev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74491/siddhadev)'s suggestion. Figured I'd add a codding sample showing how Chrome Options can be used within Selenium.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Try using HTTPS, than you should be able to remember/skip the prompt.

As an alternative you could override the security policy with the `--disable-web-security` command line option or use a faked device `--use-fake-device-for-media-stream` (which should be enough for testing).

Give it a try by creating a file `test.html` containing

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<video autoplay/>
<script>
  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio:true,video:true},
    function(stream){
      document.querySelector('video').src =
        URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    });
</script>
```

and than kill all chrome instances and start chrome like this:

```
 chrome.exe --use-fake-device-for-media-stream --disable-web-security test.html
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The page is running on HTTPS already. Outside of ChromeDriver, it's all good. It's just an issue when I start ChromeDriver using Selenium.

This isn't actually for testing; it's an exhibit kiosk in a museum that runs a program on a local webserver on a PC - so it needs real device access.